# Mapstruct throws Null Pointer Exception in Spring Boot. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I get null pointer exemption in mapstruct in Spring Boot as it couldn't be initialized.

Here is the error shown below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
```

How can I fix it?

Here is the service class shown below

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    public Page<UserDTO> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        return userRepository.findAll(pageable).map(
                userMapper::mapUsertoUserDTO  // HERE IS THE ERROR
        );
    }
```

Here is the mapper shown below

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {

    User mapUserDTOtoUser(UserDTO userDTO);

    UserDTO mapUsertoUserDTO(User user);
}
```

Here is the mapstruct in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.20</org.projectlombok.version>
        <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
    </properties>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Here is my service test shown below

@Test
public void userDtoById() {

```
    // given
    User user = new User();
    // setter

    // when
    when(userRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

    UserDTO userDto = userService.getUserById(1L);  // Here is the error

    ...
```

}

Comment: Could you post bigger part of the stacktrace?

Comment: @fascynacja I already shared all required code.

Comment: What line is the error from?

Comment: I meant error stacktrace from the logs.

Comment: @Unmitigated I shared the error line.

Comment: Usually there is more than one line.  By reading whole stack it is easier to understand the root cause

Comment: @fascynacja I shared the error line.

Comment: @fascynacja I get this error message at this line which I already shared.

Comment: The error line is not enough to know where the exception happens. It says it happens in Objects.requireNonNull, but the code you pasted does not use that method. Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @Rick I also shared the junit service test regarding the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your MapStruct to be available for injection in spring context you need to use

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
```

Comment: as UserServiceImpl has both Service and RequiredArgsConstructor (and this is the only constructor) - it is not required to add constructor manually. 
This is valid for Spring 4.3+: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.23.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-4.3

It is no longer necessary to specify the @Autowired annotation if the target bean only defines one constructor.

So second part of answer could actually be skipped

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Have not seen the RequiredArgsConstructor annotation. Have updated answer